# Configuring KDiff3 to work with AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, version-control, ankhsvn, kdiff3

I just wondered if anyone had any experiencing configuring AnkhSVN to use kdiff3 as its merge tool.

I know it can be changed in Visual Studio 2010 at Tools -> Options Subversion User Tools but I'm not sure what the correct command lines are for Diff, Merge and Patch.

I have searched the net but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to select KDiff3 from the dropdown, so there's no need to manually configure it.